# nginx reverse proxy using upstream directive

Tags: nginx, configuration, reverse-proxy

I want to configure `nginx` to be a reverse proxy using upstream directive (and add there `keepalive` for example).

```
upstream my_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3579;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_backend;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that it returns `Bad Request (Invalid host)`. And there is nothing in `nginx` error log to help me solve it.

Everything else being the same this configuration without `upstream` directive works as expected:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3579;
    }
}
```

Aren't those two equivalent? And what do I have to do to make it work with `upstream`?

Comment: What about: proxy_pass my_backend;

Comment: @itpp13 if I do that, then `nginx configtest` returns `[emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/conf.d/test.conf:9`

Comment: try adding: proxy_set_header Host $host;

Comment: @Stugal initially I tested all variables related to the `Host` header but that didn't change anything. Then I tried setting the value to `127.0.0.1` and it worked. Problem is I don't get what's the difference.